# Get Column Description from iSeries v7r1 export to Excel or Access

Tags: ibm-midrange

In my mind, getting something this simple should not be as difficult as it appears to be!

The column names are very cryptic, but I can SEE the descriptions of those columns using iSeries Navigator (or is it "Aggravator"?)

Here's a screenshot of the table definition. (Cropped out the connection info to preserve security
)
[image]
I want the values from the "Text" column, and I'm hoping to use these values from several different iSeries tables in an Access 2010 app. If it were just this one table, I would likely just type them in by hand.

I *have* been able to get most of information (less the info from this "Text" column as stated above) using the following SQL statement that I found online.
(I'm no longer sure where ... I have looked at so many ... and find most of it extremely noob-confusing!)

SELECT COLUMNS.TABLE_CATALOG, COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA, COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME, COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMNS.COLUMN_DEFAULT, COLUMNS.IS_NULLABLE, COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE, COLUMNS.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, COLUMNS.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH, COLUMNS.NUMERIC_PRECISION, COLUMNS.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, COLUMNS.NUMERIC_SCALE, COLUMNS.DATETIME_PRECISION, COLUMNS.INTERVAL_TYPE, COLUMNS.INTERVAL_PRECISION, COLUMNS.CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG, COLUMNS.CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA, COLUMNS.CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLUMNS.COLLATION_CATALOG, COLUMNS.COLLATION_SCHEMA, COLUMNS.COLLATION_NAME, COLUMNS.DOMAIN_CATALOG, COLUMNS.DOMAIN_SCHEMA, COLUMNS.DOMAIN_NAME, COLUMNS.UDT_CATALOG, COLUMNS.UDT_SCHEMA, COLUMNS.UDT_NAME, COLUMNS.SCOPE_CATALOG, COLUMNS.SCOPE_SCHEMA, COLUMNS.SCOPE_NAME, COLUMNS.MAXIMUM_CARDINALITY, COLUMNS.DTD_IDENTIFIER, COLUMNS.IS_SELF_REFERENCING
FROM SYSIBM.COLUMNS COLUMNS
WHERE (COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME='IVITMMS')

Can somebody help me out here, please?
TIA,
Don

Comment: Review this query: " SELECT substr(COLUMN_NAME,1,18), substr(TABLE_NAME,1,18), substr(TABLE_SCHEMA,1,18), COLUMN_HEADING, COLUMN_TEXT FROM qsys2.syscolumns ". Does it show data you need?

Comment: Yes! It does ... but for EVERY table

Comment: Can I add a WHERE to specify ONE table?

Comment: So add " WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<myTableName>' " or " WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<mySchemaName>' " or whatever WHERE clause is needed to get only what you want.

Comment: SELECT substr(COLUMN_NAME,1,18) AS FieldName, substr(TABLE_NAME,1,18) AS TableName, substr(TABLE_SCHEMA,1,18) AS TableSchema,  COLUMN_TEXT FROM qsys2.syscolumns WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'IVITMMS'

Comment: The above WORKS! Thank You!

Comment: @DonLeverton put in answer 10 points your losing here.  SELECT cast( COLUMN_NAME as char(20)) as cn , SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME 
    SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME, SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA , cast( COLUMN_TEXT as    
    char(50) ccsid 37) as thetext , cast( COLUMN_HEADING as char(60) 
    ccsid 37) as thehdg FROM QSYS2/SYSCOLUMN2

Comment: As a PS... This is the first time that I have ever used a "Pass Through Query" in Access, where this SQL string works equally well. I have also written some VBA code that uses this information to populate each field's Description property.

Answer (score 0):

It was a 2-part solution:

1. the PassThru Query
   `SELECT substr(COLUMN_NAME,1,18) AS ColumnName , substr(TABLE_NAME,1,18) AS TableName, substr(TABLE_SCHEMA,1,18) AS Schema,  COLUMN_TEXT FROM qsys2.syscolumns WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'BLMYPRDDTA'`
2. build a SELECT QUERY using the In() operator to filter the list of tables and their columns
   `SELECT qryPassThroughSYSCOLUMNS.*, qryPassThroughSYSCOLUMNS.TABLENAME
   FROM qryPassThroughSYSCOLUMNS
   WHERE (((qryPassThroughSYSCOLUMNS.TABLENAME) In ("COMASTR","COWOREF")));`